# Avoid memory increase in foreach loop in R

Tags: r, memory, foreach, parallel-processing, raster

I try to create summary statistics combining two different spatial data-sets: a big raster file and a polygon file. The idea is to get summary statistics of the raster values within each polygon.

Since the raster is too big to process it at once, I try to create subtasks and process them in parallel i.e. process each polygon from the `SpatialPolgyonsDataframe` at once.

The code works fine, however after around 100 interations I run into memory problems. Here is my code and what I intent to do:

```
# session setup
library("raster")
library("rgdal")

# multicore processing. 
library("foreach")
library("doSNOW")
# assign three clusters to be used for current R session
cluster = makeCluster(3, type = "SOCK",outfile="")
registerDoSNOW(cluster)
getDoParWorkers()# check if it worked

# load base data
r.terra.2008<-raster("~/terra.tif")
spodf.malha.2007<-readOGR("~/,"composed")

# bring both data-sets to a common CRS
proj4string(r.terra.2008)
proj4string(spodf.malha.2007)
spodf.malha.2007<-spTransform(spodf.malha.2007,CRSobj = CRS(projargs = proj4string(r.terra.2008)))
proj4string(r.terra.2008)==proj4string(spodf.malha.2007) # should be TRUE

# create a function to extract areas
function.landcover.sum<-function(r.landuse,spodf.pol){
  return(table(extract(r.landuse,spodf.pol)))}

# apply it one one subset to see if it is working
function.landcover.sum(r.terra.2008,spodf.malha.2007[1,])

## parallel loop
# define package(s) to be use in the parallel loop
l.packages<-c("raster","sp")

# try a parallel loop for the first 6 polygons
l.results<-foreach(i=1:6,
                   .packages = l.packages) %dopar% {
                     print(paste("Processing Polygon ",i, ".",sep=""))
                     return(function.landcover.sum(r.terra.2008,spodf.malha.2007[i,]))
                     }
```

here the output is a list that looks like this.

> l.results

```
[[1]]

9     10 
193159   2567 

[[2]]

7    9   10   12   14   16 
17  256 1084  494   67   15 

[[3]]

3      5      6      7      9     10     11     12 
2199   1327   8840   8579 194437   1061   1073   1834 
14     16 
222   1395 

[[4]]

3      6      7      9     10     12     16 
287    102    728 329057   1004   1057     31 

[[5]]

3      5      6      7      9     12     16 
21      6     20    495 184261   4765     28 

[[6]]

6    7    9   10   12   14 
161  161  386  943  205 1515
```

So the result is rather small and should not be the source of the memory allocation problem. So than the following loop upon the whole polygon dataset which has >32.000 rows creates the memory allocation which exceeds 8GB after around 100 iteratins.

```
# apply the parallel loop on the whole dataset
l.results<-foreach(i=1:nrow(spodf.malha.2007),
                   .packages = l.packages) %dopar% {
                     print(paste("Processing Polygon ",i, ".",sep=""))
                     return(function.landcover.sum(r.terra.2008,spodf.malha.2007[i,]))
                     # gc(reset=TRUE) # does not resolve the problem
                     # closeAllConnections()  # does not resolve the problem
                   }
```

What am I doing wrong?

**edit:**
I tried (as suggested in the comments) to remove the object after each iteration in the internal loop, but it did not resolve the problem. I furthermore tried to resolve eventual problems of multiple data-imports by passing the objects to the environment in the first place:

```
clusterExport(cl = cluster,
              varlist = c("r.terra.2008","function.landcover.sum","spodf.malha.2007"))
```

without major changes. My R version is 3.4 on a linux platform so supposedly also the patch of the link from the fist comment should already be included in this version. I also tried the `parallel` package as suggested in the first comment but no differences appeared.

Comment: I can only provide some guesses/suggestions. Guess 1: `foreach` exports data `r.terra.2008` and `spodf.malha.2007[i,]` to each core with each iteration. Suggestion 1: Try removing `rm()` objects on each core and then garbage collect `gc()`. (I'm not sure if `return` a value will exit you from your `%dopar%` code block.) Suggestion 2: It looks like you're still using `doSNOW`, which I've heard is not well supported (hearsay). I would try a recent version of `library(parallel)`. Look at this link `https://github.com/HenrikBengtsson/Wishlist-for-R/issues/27` as well.

Comment: none of the above worked for me (unfortunately). see my edits above.

Comment: This is actually related to the raster package. Here is some help if anyone has a related problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25426405/raster-package-taking-all-hard-drive

Answer (score 0):

You can try `exact_extract` in the `exactextractr` package. Is the fastest and memory safer function to extract values from raster. The main function is implemented in C++ and usually it doesn't need parallelization. Since you do not provide any example data I post an example with real data:

```
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(exactextractr)


# Pull municipal boundaries for Brazil
brazil <- st_as_sf(getData('GADM', country='BRA', level=2))

# Pull gridded precipitation data
prec <- getData('worldclim', var='prec', res=10)
#transform precipitation data in a dummy land use map
lu <- prec[[1]]
values(lu) <- sample(1:10,ncell(lu),replace = T)
plot(lu)

#extract land uses class for each pixel inside each polygon
ex <- exact_extract(lu, brazil)
#apply table to the resulting list. Here I use just the first 5 elements to avoid long output

lapply(ex[1:5],function(x){
  table(x[,1])#note that I use x[,1] because by default exact_extract provide in the second column the coverage fraction of each pixel by each polygon
})
```

here the example output:

```
[[1]]

 1  2  4  6  7  9 10 
 1  1  1  2  3  1  1 

[[2]]

 2  3  4  5  6  7  8 10 
 2  4  3  2  1  2  2  2 

[[3]]

 1  2  4  6  7  8  9 10 
 4  5  1  1  4  2  5  5 

[[4]]

 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 
 2  2  4  2  2  4  1  4  1  2 

[[5]]

 3  4  5  6  8 10 
 2  3  1  1  2  3
```